# Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied:

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have successfully installed and started the business network using composer.I have installed and started using these commands:

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile procurement-phase@0.0.18.bna

composer network start --networkName  procurement-phase --networkVersion 0.0.18 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

I have also imported the card created after the start of business network using :

```
composer card import --file networkadmin.card
```

Now I am trying to ping the network using the card:

```
composer network ping --card admin@procurement-phase
```

but I get

> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [composerchannel] creator org [Org1MSP]
>   Command failed

**Expected result:**

> The connection to the network was successfully tested: procurement-phase
>       version: 0.15.0-20171108090428
>       participant: org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin
>
> Command succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the certificate errors.As I got the error in docker logs of certificate authority of org1  about the incorrect  path to default ca.So i correctly specified path of the default ca folder in the volumes of ca in docker-compose.yaml .

Answer (score 0):

Is the peer running properly? If you do something like: `telnet localhost 7051` (If your peer would be in that ip and port) Do you get a connected message?

If it's another ip you should modify the connection.json file for the card.

You need to provide more information, explain the steps to took when bringing up the network, if it's the sample network...

Comment: i have edited my question by adding steps that are followed.